# my text won't blit to my display in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

i am trying to make a score in the top left corner of my screen but it is returning an error.

i have searched it up online and followed the exact steps but still it returns an error.

```
def score(rounds):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render(f'ROUND {rounds}', True, size=25)
    game_display.blit(text, (0,0))
```

render() takes no keyword arguments
i have tried putting the True in as False but that didn't work.
btw what does the middle argument True do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see the following error:

> render() takes no keyword arguments

it means, well, that the `render` function does not take keyword arguments.

Look at your code:

> `text = font.render(f'ROUND {rounds}', True, size=25)`

You call `render` with a keyword argument.

Just don't do it. Don't use a keyword argument. It's as simple as that.

Also, the third parameter has to be a color-like object, so your code should look like this:

```
text = font.render(f'ROUND {rounds}', True, pygame.Color('orange'))
```

---

Some more notes:

- `render` takes an optional 4th argument (a background color). The [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) of pygame wrongly shows it as keyword argument.
- it's better to load your fonts once. Currently, you load the font everytime you call 
  the `score` function
- instead of the `font` module, consider using the [`freetype` module](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html), which can to everything the `font` module can, and much more

Comment: thanks but now it says invalid foreground RGBA argument

Comment: @BOBTHEBUILDER What are you passing as parameter? It has to be a valid tuple describing a colour, like `(200, 0, 100)`, or a `pygame.Color` instance

Comment: The questioner probably doesn't know what a keyword argument is. Replace  "size=25" with just 25.